# How do I press hotkey ⇥

Tags: shortcut

I have an OS X application, which has shortcut

```
^⌥⇥
```

I know that it means Ctrl + Alt/Option + ???

I can't figure out what does last character mean. I tried Fn+Right, Fn+Down, it doesn't work. I have Macbook keyboard, so no "End" button here.

Comment: isn't this tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's tab.** The same character is printed on the keyboard.

Comment: not on mine keyboards. There is just the word "tab" printed.

Comment: Same here. Now I remember than this character is printed on PC keyboards, I just forgot about that, since I used it long time ago.

Comment: It's printed on my MacBook Pro keyboard @cello :)